# Regain root access to MySQL server on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, password, root

I am trying to regain root access to the MySQL database running on an Ubuntu instance (LTS 16.04.2). Problem situation is: I can start and stop MySQL using `/etc/init.d/mysql` but I cannot log in with neither of

```
mysql -u root
mysql -u root -p
```

The latter with empty password. I have an empty record in my password store. I believe to remember that login was possible without password, but maybe also I just forgot to save my password store properly. Maybe also the system is compromised. However, since I have root access, it should be possible to reset the password.

I decided to start MySQL server using

```
sudo -u mysql /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

command and can now connect with the client. As per [tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-generic), I have to issue the two commands

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
```

to set a password. When issuing the second command, I get the following warning on the console where I started the server:

```
[Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' has both a password and an authentication plugin specified. The password will be ignored.
```

I do not remember to have set up any plug-in ever. Is this Ubuntu default? Where is my MySQL password stored then, and how do I change it? Or how do I disable that plug-in I do not know about.

Comment: Are you using 5.5? I got my answer from this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71465

Answer (score 1):

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
```

... is the wrong command. In 2015 that column was deprecated and replaced by a column "authentication_string".

It should be

```
UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') where USER='root';
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do after you skip-grant-tables is connect to your database and use the mysql database.

So completly it would be:

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql.service
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
mysql -u root
use mysql;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
UPDATE user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('newpass') WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
\q
sudo killall mysqld
sudo systemctl start mysql.service
```

Comment: I tried this. It worked without errors, but afterwards `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` when trying to log in with the password just set remains.

Answer (score 0):

You'll still need to use sudo mysql -u root -p to login under the new credentials (unless you change the plugin type for the root user...)