# how to make a new account on mysql server?

Tags: mysql

I setup mysql wrong and I don't know how to change the usr/pass to get on to it. Please can somebody help me because I am new to mysql and don't know how to do this

Comment: Possibly related: [Regain root access to MySQL server on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/920637/178692)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any data in the database worth saving you can remove the package entirely and set from scratch:

```
sudo apt remove --purge mysql-server-*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql*
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Also be aware that newer versions of MySQL have a different setup mechanism than older ones using `mysql_secure_installation` to create the first user.